# Dynamically add an ActiveX control without the VS designer

Tags: c#, activex

I'm trying to dynamically add an ActiveX control to my application, without having to place it on a form.

However, when I do place the ActiveX control using the Visual Studio designer, initialization code is generation which contains a statement for setting for OcxState of the ActiveX control.

When an ActiveX control is added to a form using the designer, it seems like that the OcxState is serialized into a resources file, which is later retrieved at the initialization of the form.

Now I want to set that OcxState dynamically in code, so I can create some kind of wrapper class for the ActiveX for in my class library.

Anyone knows how to dynamically set the OcxState of an ActiveX control?

Thanks in advance!

Mathieu

Comment: Wait... the title of your post suggests that you want to dynamically add an ActiveX to your form at runtime with no help from the designer.  But your description sounds more like you're trying to dynamically create the ActiveX and not put it onto a form at all?  That isn't possible, ActiveX controls need a hosting site, which the form provides.  A component that doesn't need a hosting site would be called OLE Automation or COM and not an ActiveX control.

Answer (score 1):

i working in the same problem, the solution i got by now is working with a Worker form, that is not show, but where i can load the ocx and wrapper all the events and methods of the ocx to the outside.
In my library class i use the form like any other class instead of the ocx calls

Comment: Can you describe your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while I was working on a .NET project that requires an ActiveX control for data manipulation. I had to put the ActiveX control on a form, load it with the application and use it with a public property. Otherwise if I just create an instance of the control I loose some of the functionality.

The form does not require to be visible all the time but it provides a container where the ActiveX control can live.

Answer (score 1):

The another way is **UserControl**,
You can create a **user control** with your **ActiveX Control**. Now you can load the user control at wherever you want dynamically at runtime.